# Why is Image button in android not working..?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am making an android app. In the main class i want to call another class (Tweetlogin) with the help of image button. But as soon as i click on the image button it does not load the required result but shows unexpected error. whats wrong with my code.?
In the main class i wrote :

```
ImageButton twiter = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    twiter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Tweetlogin.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    });
```

i changed the intent line by another code but this also din't work :

```
twiter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(main.this,
                    Tweetlogin.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Tweetlogin.class);
```

To

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Tweetlogin.class);
```

And make sure your object `twiter` is not *null*

Comment: Sir, thank u for the help but this getBaseContext() din't help. When i changed the code and ran the emulator the image button is nw not clickable and no error also.

Comment: it means now its working fine, but you should confirm what you are doing in Tweetlogin class

Comment: Thank You Sir.. I resolved the error.! I will be thankful to u if u can let me know a little more abt android. Actually i am making an app by just learning through tutorials online and i get errors but there is no one to solve them. Is there any android community or site where people can help the beginners?

Comment: this is the ideal community for you to get help. but make sure you do some search for your problem before asking a question. Read the guidelines for asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Tweetlogin activity listed in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Something like:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".Tweetlogin"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: Sir, i have already added.'<activity android:name="text.Tweetlogin"></activity>'